# Get lines where the condition of i and j match

Tags: python, loops

Print each output once:

```
 f1=['part3_pl', 
     'part2_pl', 
     'part3_pl_to_p', 
     'part2_pl_to_p', 
     'part3_pl_to_p_lack', 
     'part2_pl_to_p_lack']


for i in f1:
    for j in f1:
        if i.endswith('pl') and j.endswith('pl_to_p'):
            print(i,j,i+'_output')
```

Returns:

```
part3_pl part3_pl_to_p part3_pl_output
part3_pl part2_pl_to_p part3_pl_output
part2_pl part3_pl_to_p part2_pl_output
part2_pl part2_pl_to_p part2_pl_output
```

I would like to print each line once.

Correct output:

```
part3_pl part3_pl_to_p part3_pl_output
part2_pl part2_pl_to_p part2_pl_output
```

Comment: Are you sure that's actually what your code returns?

Comment: Thanks for the notice. updated it. Do you know how to get the needed result though?

Comment: Just check `i[4] == j[4]`

Comment: The four lines that are returned are actually unique, so what you are looking for are only the lines where the first part of `i` and `j` match, right? If so, it'd be great if you could amend your question to make it clearer for people who'll come across it at a later point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly check the output again. According your code the output should have been :

```
for i in f1:
 for j in f1:
    if i.endswith('pl') and j.endswith('pl_to_p'):
        print(i,j,i+'_output')
```

Output :

```
part3_pl part3_pl_to_p part3_pl_output
part3_pl part2_pl_to_p part3_pl_output
part2_pl part3_pl_to_p part2_pl_output
part2_pl part2_pl_to_p part2_pl_output
```

The Output you desire can be achieved with the following code :

```
for i in f1:
 for j in f1:
  if i.endswith('pl') and j==i+ '_to_p':
    print(i,j,i+'_output')
```

Comment: why mine isn't giving the correct output can you explain? the only difference is `j.endswith('pl_to_p'):` and `j==i+ '_to_p':`

Comment: It is because there are two values part3_pl_to_p and part2_pl_to_p that ends with ('pl_to_p'). Therefore, for every i.endswith('pl') there will be 2 output part3_pl_to_p and part2_pl_to_p. I will suggest you to try to iterate over the code output on paper for better understanding.

Comment: Great. Thanks for explaining